# Analysis - Book recommendation with many examples

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, taylor-expansion, fourier-series, book-recommendation

I'm looking for a good math book to practice. The book should be characterized by many examples. In addition, it would be good if there were solutions to the tasks.

The book should include:

- Analysis
- Fourier series
- Infinite series
- Taylor series
- Mac Laurin series
- Laplace transformation
- Furthermore ...

Thanks for answering my question!

Comment: The book of Burn, ''Numbers and functions - Steps into analysis'' is has lot of examples, but contains not all of the topics above.

Comment: Mathematical Analysis I and II from Vladimir A. Zorich is maybe a good choice (but with no solutions?).

Comment: Similar question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1009371/book-recommendation-for-analysis-problems?rq=1

Comment: what means "many examples"? If the book is devoted to analysis it cannot have too many examples of the same topic. In general the ideas of the theory are expanded in the exercises.

Comment: Thanks for the first answers! (many examples) means many exercises :). For me it is important to have exercises, which I can solve.

Comment: "Analysis" is very broad, and I'm not sure what you mean by "infinite rows." *Advanced Calculus* by Woods discusses power series and Fourier series, as well as many other topics, with lots of computational examples. It doesn't always give complete proofs, but if you're approaching these topics from an applied perspective, it's okay. It's famous for having been the book Feynman used to learn integration techniques.

Comment: Thanks for the next answer. I just read the books (the published sites in springer, amazon). In the most books are some examples and problems, that you have to solve and thats what I want. But there are only a few exercises. I also found "Schaums calculus", I am looking for a book in this direction (lots of exercises to solve), for my exam preparation or self study. (Sorry I don't mean infinite rows, I mean infinity series)

Comment: If you can read Russian, then the problem book by Demidovich has a lot of solved problems. It's been translated into many languages, too. A bibliography can also be found here: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exercise book for Elementary/Introduction to Real Analysis?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639950/exercise-book-for-elementary-introduction-to-real-analysis)