# Exercise book on real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm looking for an exercise book on real analysis which is very rigorous and that stresses the importance of the topological aspects of the subject, meaning that I would like it to have lots of exercises on the research of internal points, accumulation points, boundary points and also lots of exercises in which the task is that of finding $sup$ and $inf$ of a set described by a sequence. Difficult exercises on series would be appreciated.

Comment: [Analysis I by Terence Tao](https://www.amazon.com/Analysis-Third-Texts-Readings-Mathematics/dp/9380250649/ref=sr_1_2?crid=2VERDVXAURSRS&keywords=analysis+i+tao&qid=1637331279&qsid=140-8455847-9278007&sprefix=analysis+I%2Caps%2C262&sr=8-2&sres=B07WHR7TDF%2C9380250649%2CB0146UVWBU%2CB07W74ZTVQ%2C366248790X%2CB07RC7MHMC%2C1594396191%2CB08LDTH5B4%2C3764371536%2C0821820508%2C1076386911%2CB00C59C6IS%2C3662462206%2C3642639305%2C1718862407%2C0821848542&srpt=ABIS_BOOK) is quite rigorous and Exercise oriented. From a cursory look at the topics you want, this book covers them well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exercise book for Elementary/Introduction to Real Analysis?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639950/exercise-book-for-elementary-introduction-to-real-analysis)

Answer (score 0):

You can download free the "problem and solution" book from any public source.
1.Rami shakarchi, pro. and solutions in undergraduate  analysis.

2. B.m.makarov,M.G.Goruzina,A.A.Lodkin,A.N.Podkorytov,
   Selected problems in real analysis.
   3.Asuman.G.Aksoy, Mohammed.A.Khamsi, a problem book in real analysis.