# Exercise books in analysis

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I'm studying Rudin's *Principles of mathematical analysis* and I was wondering if there are some exercise books (that is, books with ***solved*** problems and exercises) that I can use as a companion to Rudin.

The books I'm searching for should be:

- full of *hard*, *non-obvious*, *non-common*, and *thought-provoking* problems;
- rich of *complete*, *step by step*, *rigorous*, and *enlightening* solutions;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Real analysis text books](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/790213/real-analysis-text-books)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check these books:

[http://www.amazon.com/Problems-Analysis-Second-Charalambos-Aliprantis/dp/0120502534/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1411894207&sr=1-1&keywords=problems+in+real+analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0120502534)

And

[http://www.amazon.com/Problems-Real-Analysis-Advanced-Calculus/dp/0387773789/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1411894207&sr=1-2&keywords=problems+in+real+analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387773789)

Comment: Thanks. The second one seems very good.

Answer (score 7):

This is what I recommend to students learning analysis as a good companion:

http://minds.wisconsin.edu/handle/1793/67009

Answer (score 4):

Check these books:

[http://www.amazon.com/Problems-Variables-Lebesgue-Integration-Applications/dp/0070602212](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0070602212)

[http://www.amazon.com/Problems-Solutions-Undergraduate-Analysis-Mathematics/dp/0387982353/ref=sr_1_sc_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1411897062&sr=1-1-spell&keywords=Problems+and+Solutions+for+Undergraduate+Analysis+Rami+Shakarch](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387982353)

[http://www.amazon.com/Problems-Theorems-Analysis--Integral-Einzeldarstellungen/dp/0387056726/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1411897112&sr=1-2&keywords=George+Polya+-+Problems+%26+Theorems+in+Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387056726)

[http://www.amazon.com/Problems-Theorems-Analysis-Polynomials-Determinants/dp/3540636862/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1411897112&sr=1-3&keywords=George+Polya+-+Problems+%26+Theorems+in+Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540636862)

[http://www.amazon.com/Problems-Mathematical-Analysis-Boris-Demidovich/dp/B0007BNL1W/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1411897098&sr=1-1&keywords=Demidovich+Problems+in+Mathematical+Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0007BNL1W)

They are available online.