# Book recommendation for analysis problems

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am studying Apostol's book of Mathematical Analysis, and I am looking for problems. I have solved most of the problems in Apostol and most in Rudin, also from Folland. Can someone plese recommend any other book with decent problems? I know this question has been asked before. I need mostly proof problems. Any help or reference would be appreciated.

Thank in advance!

Comment: [Problems and Theorems in Analysis](http://www.amazon.com/Problems-Theorems-Analysis-Functions-Mathematics/dp/3540636404/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1415298630&sr=8-1&keywords=theorems+in+analysis) and see also the second volume.

Comment: You may try G.N. Berman's **A Problem Book in Mathematical Analysis**.

Comment: I can't find that book anywhere

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exercise book for Elementary/Introduction to Real Analysis?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639950/exercise-book-for-elementary-introduction-to-real-analysis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like these:

1) The 3 books of Kaczor by AMS:
[http://www.amazon.com/Problems-Mathematical-Analysis-Numbers-Sequences/dp/0821820508/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1416621683&sr=8-1&keywords=Problems+in+Mathematical+Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821820508)

2) Real Analysis by Charalambos:
[http://www.amazon.com/Problems-Analysis-Second-Charalambos-Aliprantis/dp/0120502534/ref=asap_B001IQX9TY_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1416621788&sr=1-2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0120502534)

3) Answers of Lang's analysis book:
[http://www.amazon.com/Problems-Solutions-Undergraduate-Analysis-Mathematics/dp/0387982353/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1416621683&sr=8-5&keywords=Problems+in+Mathematical+Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387982353)

Exist many other more and less advanced. For example, search by 'Problems in Mathematical Analysis' in Amazon site:
http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=Problems+in+Mathematical+Analysis

and here, e.g.:
[Exercise books in analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/949197/exercise-books-in-analysis?rq=1)

Answer (score 4):

E. Stein and R. Shakarchi's *Princeton Lectures in Analysis* have good selections of problems. Or rather, a good selection of what they call "Exercises," which are comparable to what you might find in other textbooks, and then a few of what they call "Problems," which are more involved than the standard sort of "Exercise."

Also, specifically for real analysis R. Wheeden and Antoni Zygmund's *Measure and Integral* has a large selection of exercises as well.

Edit: An important remark! Professor Wheeden is updating his book to a second edition. (Source: I'm a student at his institution.)

Comment: Wheeden/Zygmund's book is outstanding and it's sad it's not available in a cheaper edition.

Answer (score 3):

I like Richard Bass's *Real Analysis for Graduate Students*. Carother's book *Real Analysis* is pretty good too. They're both pretty advanced, but if you're already gone through Apostol, Rudin and Folland, I think you'll be able to handle them.

Answer (score 1):

There are several wonderful FREE online problem courses in various areas of mathematics by John Erdman of Portland State University available at his website here. 1

There are 5 courses in analysis written by Erdman at the site for his students-one on basic calculus, one at the advanced calculus level, one at the graduate analysis level,one on functional analysis and lastly,one on operator theory, the last 2 for advanced graduate students. These are extremely well written and comprehensive sources you will find a ton of great exercises in and that every student of mathematics should become familiar with.

And best of all,they're free! I think you'll find them very helpful.