# elementary mathematical analysis problem books recommendation

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm self study rudin pma and find that exercises in the book are more concerned with proof and lack of calculation, so I want to find a problem books but not so hard,thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you want single variable real? multi variable? functional? Bartle Sherbert is good for single variable real. Wade is good for single and multivariable real.

Comment: Apostol's *Mathematical Analysis* is a good place to look for practice problems.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/949197/81360) and [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2951319/81360).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Good book for self study of a First Course in Real Analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62212/good-book-for-self-study-of-a-first-course-in-real-analysis)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exercise book for Elementary/Introduction to Real Analysis?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639950/exercise-book-for-elementary-introduction-to-real-analysis)

Answer (score 1):

The book by Tomasz Radozycki ˙Solving Problems in Mathematical Analysis, Part I' might be interesting for you. If not, there are also Part II and Part III.

In these books a large number of individual problems are solved in a most detail manner.

Hope they work for you.

Comment: thank you , I will try your recommendation

Answer (score 0):

##### I like [Amol Sasane, *The How and Why of One Variable Calculus* (2015)](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/the-how-and-why-of-one-variable-calculus). I like its multicolored pictures!

> The exercises are plentiful, well-selected and well-constructed. Detailed solutions to all exercises are provided; they fill the last 150 pages of the book.