# A reference book of real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

I've decided to learn real analysis for the first exam about this subject at university but I'm not sure about which book to buy.

Please, can you suggest a good reference book?

Comment: Professors often suggest some books. Having a look at one of those is a starting point.

Comment: Use the search function on the site?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2207632/book-recommendation-for-real-analysis?rq=1

Comment: This can very greatly depend on what "first exam at university" you mean: what university, where, for what career...? The level of depth and covering in "real analysis" is very different for mathematics students, or for engineering ones, or for general sciences ones.

Comment: I'm studying mathematics at university

Answer (score 0):

Real Analysis by Charles Chapman Pugh is very very good. It is way more intuitive than Rudin. Rudin is terse and very good if one can do it. Carothers is also a very good option.

Comment: Which one has good practice problems ?

Comment: Carothers and Pugh....they graduate from easy to hard and are diverse. Rudin has only hard problems of a specific kind.

Comment: where can I get solutions of pugh ?

Comment: I'm studying mathematics at university and I have to learn until integration. Does Chapman's book all this topics?

Comment: @RonitDebnath I've found this:https://www.amazon.it/Real-Mathematical-Analysis-Charles-Pugh/dp/3319177702/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1496664061&sr=8-1&keywords=real+analysis+pugh#reviewBucketHeader   is Pugh this?

Comment: Yes this one springer...