# How to make sense of mathematical analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning, education, advice

I've been studying elementary analysis.  Now regarding other areas of math, say algebra and calculus, I can understand things fine as I seem to understand things by example.  Now in analysis, everything seems like Shakespearian play with no example. My question is how do I make sense out of analysis or more specifically?  How can I mould the subject to become a more exemplified version and understand faster, I don't think I'm good at abstract maths any suggestions how I may improve.

Comment: Which books have you been reading?

Comment: I found very useful the book by Robert Burn, "Numbers and functions". It's problem oriented, perfect for self learning.

Comment: Currently, I'm using "Understanding Analysis" by Abbott. I find it quite good as it discusses things from beginner point of view, its better than baby Rudin for understanding analysis as a beginner .

Answer (score 1):

Make your own examples, and find books that provide examples.  If you're a visual thinker, then find a book that uses lots of graphs, figures, and so forth.

[A start](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0198534469).

Comment: Can you suggest anything regarding Elementary analysis  (function, continuity, Reiman integration, etc ) right now I'm studying elementary analysis, is there any book regarding that topic that uses graphs, examples

Comment: Hmmm... not sure.  (It isn't my branch of math.)  But take a look at these extraordinary videos:  https://www.3blue1brown.com/

Comment: @GiornoGiovanna: *Can you suggest anything regarding Elementary analysis* --- I think Victor Bryant's book [**Yet Another Introduction to Analysis**](https://www.amazon.in/dp/052138835X) would probably be best for you at this point. See also the various answers to [Good book for self study of a First Course in Real Analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/62212/13130). Also, try browsing a university's library shelves, where you'll find a lot of books that never seem to get mentioned on the internet, such as some of those I discuss [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1744217/13130).