# Exercise books in linear algebra and geometry

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I'm studying Brannan's *Geometry* and Lang's *Introduction to Linear Algebra* and I was wondering if there are some exercise books (that is, books with ***solved*** problems and exercises) that I can use as companions.

The books I'm searching for should be:

- full of *hard*, *non-obvious*, *non-common*, and *thought-provoking* problems;
- rich of *complete*, *step by step*, *rigorous*, and *enlightening* solutions.

Comment: Ask for the books of the **Schaum's** series (Mac Graw - Hill Editors). These books contain hundreds of completely solved exercises plus hundreds of exercises with the solutions only.

Comment: @Timbuc Any other suggestion?

Comment: For linear algebra, have you looked at Paul Halmos' *Linear Algebra Problem Book*? http://www.amazon.com/Algebra-Problem-Dolciani-Mathematical-Expositions/dp/0883853221#

Comment: @Timbuc the Schaum's series does indeed have many exercises, but they are not very....hard. They are pretty trivial

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> A classic in linear algebra is Paul R. Halmos' [Linear Algebra Problem Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0883853221).
>
> In fact it's also a great book teaching many aspects of linear algebra and a great book in teaching *how to solve problems*. The first part contains more than 160 problems, the last part contains detailed solutions. A nice idea is a small chapter in between about 15 pages long, which contains *hints* for each of the problems.

The reader is encouraged even if he is able to solve a problem to also check the solution, since they may contain additional info in form of interesting comments.

I fully agree with the end of his preface:

> *I hope you will enjoy trying to solve problems.
> I hope you will learn something by doing so, and I hope you will have fun.*

Comment: Very good suggestion.

Comment: @Thanks, you're welcome. In fact I appreciate some of his books. My favorite is [Naive Set Theory](http://www.amazon.com/Naive-Set-Theory-Paul-Halmos/dp/1614271313) :-)

Comment: By the way, do you know some exercise books on geometry to use as a companion to Brannan's?

Comment: Sorry, no. I've a lot of different problem books, but none with focus geometry.

Comment: I see. Would you mind telling me the names of other problem books (in different topics) that you find useful? I'm sure that I can learn a lot from your experience.

Comment: This is a great suggestion. I really like this book.

Comment: @Dal: You may have a look at my answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871332) where I recommend problem books in analysis. Other books are presumably too specific. But at least one *treasure*: When you start studying point set topology the book [Counterexamples in Topology](http://www.amazon.com/Counterexamples-Topology-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/048668735X) is *really cool*. It's not a problem book per se, but when you are searching for topologies with certain properties, you will find there a solution.

Comment: Thank you **very** much for your kindness and your help :)

Comment: @Dal: You're welcome! And thank **you** very much for the bounty! :-) Best regards,

Answer (score 4):

Let me start by mentioning a series of books on linear algebra, by T. S. Blyth and E. F. Robertson, that I consider to be really enlightening:

*Theory + Solved Exercises*

- [Basic Linear Algebra](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Linear-Algebra-Springer-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/1852336625)
- [Further Linear Algebra](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Further-Algebra-Springer-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/1852334258/)

*Solved Exercises*

- [Algebra Through Practice: Volume 2, Matrices and Vector Spaces](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Algebra-Through-Practice-Collection-Solutions/dp/0521272866/)
- [Algebra Through Practice: Volume 4, Linear Algebra](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Algebra-Through-Practice-Collection-Solutions/dp/0521272890/)

---

And now, my secret weapons (more directed towards matrix theory):

- [Matrix Algebra](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Matrix-Algebra-Econometric-Exercises-Abadir/dp/0521537460/), by K. Abadir and J. Magnus;
- [Problems and Solutions in Introductory and Advanced Matrix Calculus](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Problems-solutions-introductory-advanced-calculus/dp/9812702024/), by Willi-Hans Steeb.

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Timbuc, the Schaum's calculus book has helped me with having many solved problems and explanations. I have seen a geometry addition being sold on amazon and ebay for a pretty good price

Comment: Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I've studied on [this](http://www.amazon.it/Problemi-risolti-algebra-lineare-Fabrizio/dp/8808132722/ref=sr_1_sc_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1412897712&sr=8-1-spell&keywords=fotuna%20luminati). Actually it's in Italian but it's a wonderful text.