# A book to prepare for analysis?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am taking Real Analysis in the Fall and the Professor recommended Spivak's Calculus to prepare for the course. Unfortunately, someone was faster than me and already borrowed the book from the library and I don't want to buy it. Does anyone have a similar book they recommend, covering advanced calculus as a preparation for real analysis? I already have Abbott's "Understanding Analysis" (he's a professor here, really nice guy, plays electric guitar in the faculty band).

Comment: Surely there must be a big list question on this site recommending introductory analysis books (in fact, I found five or six of them googling exactly that with site:math.stackexchange.com filter); by the way, if you are planning to continue with a math major, I sincerely recommend you buy Spivak's book.  It is a good investment, especially the exercises.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Good book for self study of a First Course in Real Analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62212/good-book-for-self-study-of-a-first-course-in-real-analysis)

Answer (score 4):

I do recommend Bartle's "Introduction to Real Analysis". It's the book that I used and it was really helpful, since it explains everything in a good and clear way.

Other option is Apostol's "Calculus".

Answer (score 0):

Read, the book written byelon lages lima, IMPA, is a very good book, in general in brazil, the impa have a good books.