# Easing Undergraduate Real Analysis course

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, reference-request

Combining Spivak and Apostol Calculus' textbook is enough (or too much) to prepare someone to take an undergraduate Real Analysis course? Would you have a better (and less time consuming) suggestion?

Comment: Rudin's PMA is the best (of course, IMO) real analysis book in existence. If that seems very thorough, then Bartle-Sherbert is a very good (again, IMO) replacement.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, I'm looking for some good Calculus (and other subjects if need be) to prepare to take a summer Real Analysis course. The Calculus I had (15 years ago!) was very rudimentary. Of course, an introductory Real Analysis is not discarded, but I'm afraid I'm not mature (mathematically speaking) even for Baby Rudin.

Comment: It depends on your notion of time-consuming, but I found Francis Su's [lecture videos](http://analysisyawp.blogspot.com/) very helpful in my undergrad course.

Comment: Thanks, already bookmarked!

Comment: @DanielFugisawa Although you may lack mathematical maturity, the maturity you have in order to say this is something to be cherished and will most certainly be something very positive for you. 

Back to the question, I read Calculus With Analytic Geometry in order to learn Calculus. I found it a really good book, but I don't really think it was very helpful in order to understand analysis. I think reading some introductory book on analysis will be far more helpful.

Comment: Maybe you're right. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @DanielFugisawa I think Apostol is really good preparation for a first course in real analysis (don't skip the introduction!), if you can get through it.  Also, if you are interested, I've been blogging all of the solutions to Apostol, Volume 1 (the link is in my profile).  Maybe you'll find some of the solutions helpful.

Comment: Best news of the night!!!! Thank you! I never know if I got the right answer. Already bookmarked it!

Comment: @DanielFugisawa No problem.  Let me know if you find mistakes (which definitely exist).  I'm only just now finishing blogging chapter 4, so nowhere near the whole book yet, but at least it's something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the suggestions in this closely related MSE question - ["Good book for self study of a First Course in Real Analysis"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62212).