# How important is the choice of books in studying Analysis?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, education, book-recommendation

I am in a fix. I have done a graduate course in Pure Mathematics.I love to  study abstract algebra.I want to do postgraduate in Mathematics especially in Abstract Algebra .

In order to enter a postgraduate program I have to qualify a screening test which comprises of three sections:

1. Algebra
2. Analysis
3. Metric Spaces and Topology

I appeared in the test the earlier year .Though I scored a perfect 10 in **Algebra**,my marks in the other two topics were $3$ and $4$ out of $10$ as a result of which I failed  to qualify.

Is it possible to learn *Analysis* now or its too late.Can I speed up the process of learning *Analysis*?Can someone  please give some tips on how should I read this topic?I don't know why I fail in this topic very badly.Though I have studied topics like **Continuity,Differentiablity,Riemann-Integral,Sequence and series of functions etc.**,I fail in these topics miserably.Do I need to start from scratch now?

Also I more question I find that people ask for recommendation of books in *Analysis*.How important is the choice of books in a particular topic.We followed **Rudin-Principles of Mathematical Analysis** in our course.

In short please give some tips on how to study *Analysis* .I know there are many on this site who are very good at analysis.Any recommendations will be helpful

Comment: 1. It is never too late to learn Analysis. 2. The book you will use is important 3. Rudin is an unimaginative, unintuitive, boring, banal, dry  book of which for a mysterious reason some American professors (and only they) are enamored   4. I highly recommend Lang's [Undergraduate Analysis](http://www.amazon.com/Undergraduate-Analysis-Texts-Mathematics/dp/0387948414) or at a more advanced level his  [Real and Functional analysis](http://www.amazon.com/Functional-Analysis-Graduate-Texts-Mathematics/dp/0387940014#reader_0387940014) They are great books written by a great mathematician.

Comment: Do these books develop the subject of analysis in **detail**,I usually found **Lang's** Complex Analysis quite dry

Comment: Yes, Lang's   Real and Functional Analysis has a superb selection of topics but is indeed  a bit dry . Juicy examples can be found in Buck's [*Advanced Calculus*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=7cYQAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA588&lpg=PA588&dq=buck+calculus&source=bl&ots=UTzO3U_Y-H&sig=lTPy7gfOQa1tn144Iw-RWbiI5nY&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidw_PdycDKAhXImBoKHQOrCkwQ6AEIezAM#v=onepage&q=buck%20calculus&f=false), which is very rich in examples, applications, calculations and above all simple illuminating pictures. (I have a soft spot for that  book, which  was my introduction to serious Analysis.)

Comment: So if you don't mind can you please give a list of books sequentially which you think would help me develop my intuition of **Analysis** clearly

Comment: I am really looking forward to you and your guidance on how to approach this subject

Comment: Or the books that helped you develop the topic

Comment: First and simultaneously Buck and Lang's undergraduate book. Then Lang's Real and Functional Analysis.

Comment: Are topological spaces part of the curriculum, or just metric spaces?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Good book for self study of a First Course in Real Analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62212/good-book-for-self-study-of-a-first-course-in-real-analysis)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are talking about the fundamentals, for the one-variable case I can only recommend Spivak's excellent book "Calculus". I learnt a lot from it even before I entered university and it has provided me with intuition which has been very helpful ever since.

For multivariable calculus things aren't so clear for me. I'm not really sure whether there exists a vector calculus textbook which is actually good, since I learnt from lecture notes and solidified my knowledge from experience in electromagnetism and differential geometry (btw if you're into that, you may benefit from O'Neill's "Elementary differential geometry"). 
At any rate, I enjoyed Marsden & Tromba's book "Vector Calculus", which is however not very rigorous. You can again go for Spivak's little monster called "Calculus on Manifolds", but be warned: the notation is kind of irritating from time to time and it is more oriented towards geometry, not to mention that it is extremely laconic compared to his other books.

Rudin's book is great but in my opinion it can only be of use if you are exceptionally good or have already a solid background in analysis. A fantastic book which has a lot of overlap with Rudin is Apostol's "Mathematical Analysis", which covers even more material but in a much friendlier manner. I guess this last one is probably what you are looking for.

Finally, concerning metric spaces, I'd suggest Kaplansky's "Set Theory and Metric Spaces", the "metric spaces"-part of which has appealed to me ever since I read it for the first time. He has very well placed definitions and really enlightening exercises. I'd also consider Simmons' "Introduction to topology and modern analysis", for which I have a soft spot as it has been the first book I read metric space theory from. His language initially seemed kind of strange but I finally realized how fitting and natural it is.

I think that I would begin with Spivak, then move to Marsden&Tromba for a little while and then to Apostol and Kaplansky.

Now, concerning "strategic" advice, I can't say much since you are not providing sufficient information on your background, but for some reason my guess is that your exams were less computational and more "theoretical" than you expected. In this case, I'd say you can take Apostol's book for example and fill every proof you can on your own. If you do this I believe that you'll be more than ready (:

Good luck with your tests!