# Prequisite for understanding Abel's work

Tags: analysis

Hi I hope this question is not too soft

I am curious about the work of Abel.

I have found his work in this link http://www.abelprize.no/nedlastning/litteratur/houzel_the_work.pdf

Currently I have some proof based knowledge from highschool calculus, vector, differential equations etc. and some knowledge about sets and de morgan laws.

Which kind of prequisite do I need to have in order to understand Abel's work (look in the link)

Comment: You gotta love Norwegian as a language: "nedlastning" for "download" in that link, it's great (it is a very literal translation)! On a more serious note, I think this is fairly high level stuff, for which you will definitely need some analysis (real and complex). But good idea to look at a body of work in this way, best of luck!

Comment: Thanks. Ive been trying to go through abbotts understanding analysis, but I find it quite difficult for self study. Do you think spivak would be a more gentle start? (I will probably start as an undergraduate in august in math)

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62212/good-book-for-self-study-of-a-first-course-in-real-analysis). Also for an intuitive/visual approach to complex analysis, consider *Visual Complex Analysis* by Tristan Needham.