# What are the best introductions on analysis, to read for leisure?

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question, book-recommendation

I was just wondering if anyone could recommend a book on mathematical analysis that is interesting enough to sit down and read for enjoyment alone? Something not written in the style of a textbook?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Good book for self study of a First Course in Real Analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62212/good-book-for-self-study-of-a-first-course-in-real-analysis)

Answer (score 2):

Counterexamples in Analysis is great for recreational reading.

Answer (score 2):

[Understanding Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1493927116) is an awesome book in my opinion. It's concise and highly readable, but manages to not sacrifice too much rigor when doing so. I think it's a great book for someone who is interested in getting their hands on serious material, but in an accessible and easy to read fashion.

Comment: +1 Its a great book, i forgot to write it in my answer. Now i remember

Answer (score 2):

Tom Körner's got a couple:

- *Calculus for the Ambitious*
- *A Companion to Analysis: A second first and first second course in analysis.*

All of his stuff is extremely readable, whether it's formatted like a textbook or otherwise. (His book on Fourier analysis is easily one of the best, but probably a bit advanced for what the OP has in mind.)

And of course I have to recommend Hardy's *A Course in Pure Mathematics*, even if it is explicitly a textbook. Boy did Hardy know how to write.

Answer (score 1):

I remember Visual Complex Analysis by Tristan Needham being enjoyable for armchair reading.

Answer (score 1):

There are two books according to me

1. How to Think About Analysis 1st Edition
   by Lara Alcock

[https://www.amazon.com/Think-About-Analysis-Lara-Alcock/dp/0198723539](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198723539)

2.
The Real Analysis Lifesaver: All the Tools You Need to Understand Proofs (Princeton Lifesaver Study Guides) Reprint Edition
by Raffi Grinberg

[https://www.amazon.com/Real-Analysis-Lifesaver-Understand-Princeton/dp/0691172935/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1491669108&sr=1-1&keywords=analysis+lifesaver](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691172935)

Both these books are written in informal way suitable for self study

Hope it heps

Answer (score 1):

The Manga Guide to Calculus might be of use:
[The Mange Guide to Calculus](https://www.nostarch.com/mg_calculus.htm)

Answer (score 1):

An Introduction to Mathematical Analysis by Burkill is nice and concise, yet still flows very well and has a few good exercises. Only covers basic analysis though, nothing beyond first or maybe second year undergrad. I also like that it is smaller so you can carry it around to read on a bench or on a train.

Answer (score 1):

Iosevich, *A View from the Top : Analysis, Combinatorics and Number Theory*

Answer (score 1):

For an easy and fun book read Understanding Analysis by Abbott. For a tougher read that is thorough and intuitive read Real Mathematical Analysis by C.C.Pugh.I would recommend this over Rudin anyday.

Answer (score 1):

> I recommend
>
> - *[Analysis by its History](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387770313)* by E. Hairer and G. Wanner
>
> and
>
> - *[A Radical Approach to Real Analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0883857472)* by D.M. Bressoud.

Answer (score 0):

Your description led me to think that you want a book speaking in a tone like you are strolling with a seasoned mathematician. Then two books came to my mind:

1. The Way of Analysis by R. S. Strichartz;
2. Analysis (three volumes) by R. Godement.

The latter one is in addition entertaining, in the sense that the author is actually a comedian whose sense of humor is unique and superb.

Also check out Princeton's Companion to Mathematics; you can get inspired as you can see mathematics from the viewpoints of the experts of the experts.

Comment: Are these suitable for beginners and self study?

Comment: @J.Deff, That is a separate question. Whether the OP is a beginner or not cannot be told from the OP's question itself.

Comment: I am asking for myself

Comment: @J.Deff The former is suitable for both. He does one rather bold thing for analysis which is using $1/n$ and $1/m$ instead of $\epsilon$ and $\delta$. This in and of itself I actually find to be a good thing because it emphasizes the idea that these are not just small positive numbers but small positive numbers that *change* (so I set $n=1$, I ask what $m$ can be; I set $n=2$; I ask what $m$ can be now; etc.) My one very serious gripe is that at one point in the book he, without comment, abruptly interchanges the role of $n$ and $m$, leaving it that way for the rest of the book.

Comment: @J.Deff, Oh haha :) Got'ya wrong. I would say it depends on your current working knowledge. If you already can follow the theorem-proof style exposition then probably you can follow the books. But if you currently can only do computation well, then I am not sure about it :).

Comment: @EricClapton no problem mate. i am just a starter

Comment: @J.Deff My other negative comment is not a complaint at all really, but I will say that Strichartz is an absolutely atrocious reference. It is definitely meant to be *read*, in the sense that there is substantive content embodied in the middle of paragraphs. But I do find this nearly unavoidable; it seems to me that a math book will almost always be either a bad reference or a bad linear read or both.

Comment: @Ian Okay thanks