# Tips for a dum-dum : Introduction to Analysis 1 and 2

Tags: analysis, reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

First off let me say that math and I don’t get along. I want to be it’s friend, but it certainly doesn’t want to be mine. I have been out of high school for some time (decades) and recently returned to college. I saw these classes listed as math requirements on my new major and got rather worried.

I have a learning disability related to math. Despite the username, I’m not a completely stupid person however math never clicks in my head. It was a struggle to pass algebra 1, and I can’t say I remember anything about that class from last year.

I wanted to ask this forum if there were any recommended books, apps, YouTube videos, etc. that they could recommend in regards to Analysis. I’d like to read a book or take an app class (like Khan Academy) that will help me prepare for this class. Even if it’s using Khans Academy to retake a specific class that I might need to take to refresh or prepare for the classes. I didn’t see they offered anything for Analysis.

I have looked on amazon and there are a wide variety of books, and no shortage of YouTube videos, but I guess I am looking to see if anyone had recommendations for people like me, where math is a terrifying subject that makes little sense.

Thanks

Comment: It might depend on what your major calls “analysis.” In mathematics it likely means “real analysis” and is the class where you prove things about sets, functions, continuity, and integration.

Comment: One takeaway from such class is the (useful) ability to see a definition and then know what it means to prove that something satisfies that definition, which is certainly useful in other majors. With this skill, the first 1-2 lines of any proof typically “write themselves,” which often removes the “I have no idea how to start” panic.

Comment: thank you!  It is not a mathematics degree, and actually no where near it (psych) so I was surprised to see it listed as the math requirement. I was also surprised to see it listed as math 101 and 102 (guessing the intro part plays into that). Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Good book for self study of a First Course in Real Analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62212/good-book-for-self-study-of-a-first-course-in-real-analysis)

Answer (score 1):

For complex analysis,  try Tristan Needham's "Visual Complex Analysis" (http://usf.usfca.edu/vca/).

For real analysis, I suggest David Bressoud's "A Radical Approach to Real Analysis" https://www.maa.org/press/books/a-radical-approach-to-real-analysis.

There are many good online courses on eDX (https://www.edx.org/) and MIT OCW (https://ocw.mit.edu/index.htm) if you want something more structured and complete than YouTube videos which typically don't include the notes, worksheets, etc.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the response.

Comment: No problem. Also look here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62212/good-book-for-self-study-of-a-first-course-in-real-analysis/62322#62322