# Real analysis existence of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis

Does there exist continuous onto function from $[0,1)$ to $(0,1)$.

I have made some conclusions. Such function can not be one in a neighborhood of zero.
Please help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please add some context to the problem and what have you tried?

Comment: Perhaps the simple $f(x)=x$?

Comment: See if f is one one in a nbd of zero.. Then by approaching 1, I can approach either 0 or 1. So range can not be (0,1)

Comment: Consider $f(x) = 1/2 + 1/2*x*\sin(\frac{1}{1-x})$ on the domain [0,1).

Comment: @john_lathrop, it's range is (0,1)?

Comment: I've clarified in an answer below

Comment: How did you think of this? Can you give another function?

Comment: This is a problem that seems to be testing knowledge of the extreme value theorem. We need to take advantage of the open bound of our domain, otherwise the EVT would apply (therefore making the statement false). Any function that attains $0$ and $1$ repeatedly as $x\rightarrow \infty$ can be substituted instead of $\sin$, so that $\frac{1}{1-x}\rightarrow \infty$ as $x\rightarrow 1$.

Comment: Great..can you suggest me book where I can get more such questions of this type.

Comment: Any real analysis textbook that includes chapter problems should have some on functions on open/closed sets and testing knowledge of theorems. See [this other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62212/good-book-for-self-study-of-a-first-course-in-real-analysis) for a variety of analysis textbooks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the function $f:[0,1)\rightarrow(0,1)$ defined as $f(x) = 1/2 + 1/2*x*\sin(\frac{1}{1-x})$. I've attached an image of a graph of $f(x)$ to hopefully aid understanding of what's going on with $f$:

[image]

$f$ is enclosed in the envelope bound by $y_{upper} = \frac{x+1}{2}$ and $y_{lower} = \frac{-x+1}{2}$ and is therefore will not attain $y=0$ or $y=1$ on $[0,1)$.

However for any $y$ value arbitrarily close to 1, there will be some $x$ near 1 s.t. $\frac{1}{1-x} = \pi/2 + 2\pi k$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, so that $f(x)=1/2+1/2*x = \frac{x+1}{2}$, which approaches 1 as $x\rightarrow1$.

Similarly, for any desired $y$ value close to 0, there will be $x$ near 1 s.t. $\frac{1}{1-x} = 3\pi/2 + 2\pi k$, so that $f(x) = 1/2 + 1/2*x*(-1) = \frac{-x+1}{2}$, which approaches 0 as $x\rightarrow1$.

Comment: Very nice answer +1 ! .Thanks.