# Infimum of this set?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

In class we discussed the set $B=\{b\in\mathbb{R}|b^2>2\}$ has a supremum and infimum with respective values $\infty$ and -$\infty$.

We were given the problem of showing $sup(A)=inf(B)$ given $A=\{a\in\mathbb{Q}|a^2<2\}$ and $B=\{b\in\mathbb{Q}|b^2>2\}$. I know $sup(A)=\sqrt{2}$, but why does $inf(B)=\sqrt{2}$ with the set of rational numbers compared to the real numbers?

Comment: $B$ should be $\{b\in\Bbb Q_{\ge 0}:b^2>2\}$.

Comment: I don't know what that distinction means.

Comment: $B$ should be $\{b\in\Bbb Q:b^2>0\text{ and }b\ge 0\}$; does that help?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but barely. I appreciate your help, though.

Comment: The point is that if you limit yourself to non-negative rationals (or reals) in the definition of $B$, then $\inf B$ actually is $\sqrt2$: it was only the negative numbers in the original version of $B$ that loused things up and gave you an infimum of $-\infty$.

Comment: Oh. Thanks. Are you able to recommend any supplemental texts in real analysis? We're using Abbott's Understanding Analysis but evidently it's not helping.

Comment: It’s probably been a good 30 years since I last taught real analysis, so I no longer have any real feel for the available texts. In particular, I’m not familiar with Abbott, so it would be difficult to suggest something really complementary. (I do know that a number of folks have [recommended](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62212/good-book-for-self-study-of-a-first-course-in-real-analysis) it for self-study.) I strongly suspect that others here could give you better advice.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it.

Comment: You’re welcome; good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I need it. This is what happens when a statistician is thrown into an analyst's paradise.

Comment: As Brian says, you should throw away the negative reals and rationals for the purpose of this question. It might help to understand it, if you draw the graph of y=x^2, for x>=0, and the horizontal line y=2, together. Now try to shade on the horizontal axis those positive real numbers whose square is less than 2, and in a different colour, those whose square is greater than 2.